# Transferring files from Python to C# via sockets

Tags: c#, python, unicode

I'm trying to read all kinds of files from a python server, and transfer it into the C# client to save it. In most file it works pretty well, but in files like MP3 it corrupts it and replaces the weird Unicode symbols to text such as:

> ff\xfb\xd2d\x00\x0f\xf0\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\r \x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\xa4\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x004\

Here's some of my code

```
byte[] converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(res);
saved.Write(converted, 0, converted.Length);

saved.Close();
```

Is there a way to reverse these in C# into Unicode, or a way to get around it?

Comment: Why are you converting the files into unicode instead of just transferring the raw bytes?

Comment: @ChristophTerasa when loading the file or in C#, saving?

Comment: Well, I'd think you'd open the file in python, read some bytes via `read()`, and then transfer those bytes on the socket to the C# program, which accepts those and puts them as-is into another file.